# Could someone please clarify my understanding of this question?

Tags: ip, network, subnet

I have been asked to use a particular IP address for a homework lab. The IP address is 218.179.169.7 and I have been asked to create 24 subnets and use the 16th network address. I dont fully understand what is being asked of me here but have devised that to allow for 24 subnets it would have to have a prefix of /29
making the 16th network address: 218.179.169.120 with the first host being: .121 and the last host: .126

is this the answer you would expect from me and if not what would your solution be?

Thank you very much! Apologies for the tedious question but my teachers are unavailable for contact at the moment.

Comment: Homework and test questions are off limits here, however this is explained in detail in the 2-part answer located [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).

Comment: To start with, you cannot subnet an IP address. You can subnet a network address or prefix with a specific mask.